# Java Reactor : unhandled exception from map(), but is handled from a fromCallable()

Tags: java, reactor

In the following two examples, the first one (with the `map()`) tells me that there's an unhandled exception from `readTree()`, but not in the second example. Why so ? Thx!

```
Mono.just(jsonString)
.map(jsonString1 -> {
    return new ObjectMapper().readTree(jsonString1);
})
.onErrorResume(IOException.class, error -> {
    return Mono.error(new InvalidContentException("error with the JSON. " + error));
})
```

```
Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
    return new ObjectMapper().readTree(jsonString);
})
.onErrorResume(IOException.class, error -> {
    return Mono.error(new InvalidContentException("error with the JSON. " + error));
})
```

Answer (score 6):

`Mono.fromCallable` :- Uses Callable as the parameter and creates a new `MonoCallable` object which extends `Mono`.So `callable` is a FunctionalInterface which has a method `call()` so this call method throws an exception.

For Example :- 
This won't throw an exception

```
Callable<JsonNode> callableObj = () -> new ObjectMapper().readTree(jsonString);
```

but when we call the method `call()` this will throw an exception.

`callableObj.call();`

So when we call this we are creating a MonoCallable over here,hence it is not throwing an exception.Since it is of the type `Callable`.

```
Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
    return new ObjectMapper().readTree(jsonString);
})
```

So when we apply a downstream call on this such as `map` or `flatMap` it will call the `call()` method. So if an exception occours it will be wrapped into MonoError and we don't have to explicitly handle.

This is the reason why `readTree` was not throwing error in `Mono.fromCallable`.

For further reference you can check callable here :-
[javadoc for callable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) where you can check that until you call `call()`
it won't throw an exception.

Whereas in this case :-

```
Mono.just(jsonString)
.map(jsonString1 -> {
    return new ObjectMapper().readTree(jsonString1);
})
.onErrorResume(IOException.class, error -> {
    return Mono.error(new InvalidContentException("error with the JSON. " + error));
})
```

It is returning `MonoMap` which extends `Mono` in the `.map` call hence we have to handle it.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that Mono.fromCallable is taking one Callable interface which is able to throw one exception. However, map takes Function interface which does not throw any exception. But the code inside

```
.map(jsonString1 -> {
return new ObjectMapper().readTree(jsonString1);})
```

might throw one checked exception. So the static syntax checking will report error. If map throws one runtime exception, It will not report any error. So one approach is to

```
try {
    //code that might throw checked exception

} catch(IOException e) 
{
  throw new RuntimeException(e)
}
```